# Remove default player Play, Seek, Full screen bar in MPMoviePlayerViewController iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-processing

I am using a MPMoviePlayerViewController in my iOS application and when i am playing video it displaying a default bar for play/pause, seek bar and full screen button. and i do not want to show this bcoz i want to do this from my own controls. so please can any one suggest me how i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPMoviePlayer has got a `controlStyle` attribute that you can set to `MPMovieControlStyleNone` like shown below

```
mpMoviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. now i want to add my custom buttons on full screen view. you have any idea about this? Please suggest... thx

Comment: i don't think that you can do this in "real" fullscrenn view. you just have to resize the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`'s view's frame to the size of the screen. after that you can add other ui controls to the view.

Comment: @MiteshKhatri you can to that in both scenarios. For fullscreen (the real one), you can add your custom interface to the current keyWindow and for fake-fullscreen or embedded mode you may add it to the MPMoviePlayerController's view.